# Execute Alert Before location.reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery confirm min js. and use alert in my ajax code.

The problem is when my ajax code runs first it gives priority to locationReload and reload. I want to run alert first then reload.

One thing I note that if I use Simple `ALERT('some')` so it works but this can't.

My code is as follow

```
success:   function(data) { 
  $.alert({
      title: 'Message!',
      content: data,
      theme: 'material',
      animation: 'zoom',
      animationBounce: 2.5, 
  });
  //$('#thmb_prev').html(data);
  $('#loader').hide();
  location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use confirm box instead of alert then. So once you click on ok, then it will get reloaded. Try the below. you can find samples [here](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

```
$.confirm({
    title: 'Message!',
      content: data,      
    buttons: {        
        OK: {
            location.reload();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript interpreter executes the code in one thread, it doesn't wait for the dialog to close. The `alert()` blocks the thread until it is closed. That's why it seems to work fine in your case.

But to do what you want here, you need to use callbacks, as described in the [documentation](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#callbacks).

```
success: function(data) { 
  $.alert({
      title: 'Message!',
      content: data,
      theme: 'material',
      animation: 'zoom',
      animationBounce: 2.5,
      onClose: function () {
        // Do whatever you want when the dialog is about to be closed
        location.reload();
      }
  });
  //$('#thmb_prev').html(data);
  $('#loader').hide();
}
```

Comment: i use reload because ajax php page update some data. and i want to show that updated data. so for that i use location reload.